# extract values from ARIMA model summary in python

Tags: python, arima

I want to extract particular values from arima results summary. For e.g. Model and AIC to save in a dataframe. I am getting below mentioned table on running result.summary

## ARIMA Model Results

```
Dep. Variable:          D.Order_Count   No. Observations:                  543
Model:                 ARIMA(4, 1, 4)   Log Likelihood               
-1589.811
Method:                       css-mle   S.D. of innovations              4.492
Date:                Wed, 11 Apr 2018   AIC                           3199.622
Time:                        12:35:05   BIC                           3242.593
Sample:                    07-02-2015   HQIC                          3216.424
                     - 07-31-2017
```

How to do this in Python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `fit` object. It has attribute `aic`: for example,

```
arima_model = ARIMA(df['mm'],order=(7,1,1))
arima_fit = arima_model.fit()
print(arima_fit.aic)
```